# Linking against GLib using VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, glib

I have msys2 installed on windows10, and I'm recompiling my linux projects to work on windows. So far, there is little problem, everything works fine when I compile using clang or gcc. But I'm unable to link using VS2017.

I can repro the issue with a hello world, basically, it's just this one line of code:

```
g_print ("Hello World\n");
```

and I get error

> LNK2019: unresolved external symbol g_print referenced

Obviously, I have to tell the linker about glib, but how? I've tried pluging in C:\msys64\mingw64\lib and other likely folders into the linker properties, but I can't seem to find the magic incantation. I just keep getting the same error. What do I need to tell it? Or am I just wasting time on the impossible?

Answer (score 0):

I got a better error message from VSCode - unable to find glib-2.0.lib.
Of course not, no such file exists. So I renamed libglib-2.0.dll.a to glib-2.0.lib, and renamed libintl.dll.a to intl.lib, and now it compiles, links, and runs just fine from VS2017.

This is a terrible solution. In my opinion, Gnome should supply better quality distros.

Comment: Please file a bug on [GNOME Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=glib) rather than complaining on StackOverflow. The upstream developers should be able to help or fix the bug, if this is a bug.

Comment: Not reporting a bug. Just asking for help. You remember 'help' -something you used to get on stackoverflow.

Comment: This looks like a bug, or at least a documentation problem in GLib, so should be treated as such. StackOverflow is not a bug reporting system (or a database of workarounds) for fixable upstream issues.

Comment: It's a differnce in implementation by 2 vendors - msvc vs mingw. That is not a bug.
My reference to Gnome distro quality is the gaps in platform coverage, in this case, the lack of binaries for the windows platform. Again, that is not a bug, just a lack of commitment by Gnome.

Comment: MSYS2 is a distribution that uses mingw, so it is a minimal Unix like development environment rather than purely Windows native. Maybe they could change the names of the files to make it easier with the MSVC case, I don't know. The point is MSYS2 is a distribution, just like Fedora, Ubuntu, etc. for Linux and Homebrew for macOS. I'm not aware of a purely Windows distribution for GNOME binaries, but there are some guides, e.g. https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK+/Win32/MSVCCompilationOfGTKStack, and tools https://wiki.gnome.org/msitools if anyone wishes to work on that.